# Sockets->program causes missing last character

Tags: c#, php, .net, sockets, networkstream

#### Purpose

For this program, the intent is to have a html form send uploaded files to a server running a C# listener. So far sending the file works, and it gets dealt with, but then running the file does not work right.

This has been narrowed down to a missing byte seemingly at the end of the file. Manually adding the missing byte works for testing purposes, but it is not practical for dynamic versions.

#### Outcome

In one file type, it is a bad footer, and it seems the same in the other accepted type as well.

This is what is accessing the sent data.

```cs
TcpListener tcp = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
// then the stream...
int read = net.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < read ; i++)
bw.Write(buffer[i]);
```

```php
socket_send($sock, $data, strlen($data), 1);
```

And the PHP that sends the data is structured in the create, connect, send, close. The file is managed by POST, `file_get_contents($file)`, and `filesize($file)` for the socket.

#### Question [updated]

> Since the data is sent as a raw string, does the problem of the missing byte lie in the method of sending or receiving?

The reason for why there is the missing data is still uncertain. It originates from the sending the file that was just uploaded, using PHP, to another destination through the network. What causes the missing data?

#### *Update*

Adding an `async` begin/end to the stream reading the data was tried. Although. this missing `char` could be due to an oddity in the PHP socket usage.

Moving the uploaded file that was sent to the server through PHP resolved the missing byte/char problem, although it doesn't exactly answer why there is missing data.

So the problem lies in sending from the server itself using the PHP sockets.

Comment: Reading Synchronously can miss byes and cause OverFlow errors.  Have had these issues with every version of Microsoft Operating System since the original 8080 PCs.  The solution is to use Asynchronous Events to read the Port.  With your code there are additional issues.  TCP max datagram size is approximately 1500 bytes.  Datagrams can be split and combined during routing.  So your read may not read the entire message.  So you must read to the End character (like a return) or with binary include a byte count at beginning of message indicating the number of character to follow.

Comment: @jdweng any more details or documentation on 'Reading Synchronously can miss byes and cause OverFlow errors.' ? I'm genuinely curious. I've never encountered an issue like this from reading synchronously (even with very large files and slow connections) and would be interested in where the issue may occur.

Comment: It really depends on other processes on the machine.  If other processes lock the task switching you can have issues.  It also depends on the size of you buffers.   I've had a lot more issues with Serial Ports than TCP.  but TCP datagrams are max 1500 bytes and it is possible the datagrams take different routes.  So the receive end of the ethernet (at the network card) has to reassemble the receive datagrams in order causing irregular timing.  Also when you have retries due to CRC errors you get irregular timing. Slow connections reduces the risk of overflow, not decrease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the stage of *sending* the data once the HTML form completed and the file was uploaded to the server.

It went awry with the flag set in the `socket_send` section of the PHP script.

```php
socket_send($sock, $data, strlen($data), 0);
```

Setting the flag to 0, instead of 1, stopped the truncating.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the file is larger than the size of the buffer you're reading the file into, not surprising that the file is not downloaded completely - you read the input stream only once

Comment: Not very likely.  More likely the message is coming in multiple reads and you have to read until end of message which may take more than one read.

Comment: @jdweng anyhow reading from input stream just once relying on the fact that the file would fit into the buffer is not correct - he should read the stream in the loop until end of stream is reached

Comment: you're stating the same thing with me actually

Comment: Yes, it appears that way. There was a buffer that refilled, just not in the question's code sample..

Comment: @mangusta : You said Buffer which is usually a lot smaller than the data being read.  This issue has nothing to do with the size of the buffer.  The buffer is usually a temporary buffer and is usually around 4K Bytes. while receive data can be very large.

Comment: @jdweng I was not referring to the socket's buffer, I was writing about variable "buffer" that the OP used to store the data from input stream. Those are different things

Comment: Again, this issue has nothing to do with the size of the buffer.  Buffer is a temp buffer and the receive data should be put into something that is not a temporary buffer.

Comment: @jdweng I never stated that the data should be put into temporary buffer. You gotta re-read my answer, your comments don't make any sense